# how to save state of dynamically created checkbox in android ie, once i checked multiple check box it should stay checked untill user manually uncheck

Tags: java, android, checkbox, dynamic

how to save state of dynamically created checkbox in android ie, once i checked multiple check box it should stay checked untill user manually uncheck android java

please help me out

how to save state of dynamically created checkbox in android ie, once i checked multiple check box it should stay checked untill user manually uncheck android java

how to save state of dynamically created checkbox in android ie, once i checked multiple check box it should stay checked untill user manually uncheck android java
how to save state of dynamically created checkbox in android ie, once i checked multiple check box it should stay checked untill user manually uncheck android java

```
   btn_previewA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                playerList.clear();
                selectedPlayerDetailsList.clear();
                selectedPID.clear();

                for (int j = 0; j < squad_count; j++) {
//            while (teamA_table.getChildCount() > 0) {
                    TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) teamA_table.getChildAt(j);
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) tableRow.getChildAt(0);
                    if (cb.isChecked()) {
                        playerList.add(cb.getText().toString());
                        selectedPlayerDetailsList.add(playerDetailsList.get(j));
                        selectedPID.add(playerDetailsList.get(j).getPlayerID());
                        Log.d("checked", "playerList = " + playerList);
                        Log.d("checked", "selectedPlayerDetailsList = " + selectedPlayerDetailsList);
                        Log.d("checked", "selectedPID = " + selectedPID);
                    }

//            }
                }

                Log.d("checked", "playerList.size() = " + playerList.size());
                Log.d("checked", "playerA = " + playerA);

                if (playerList.size() == playerA) {
//                    preview();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SelectTeamAXIActivity.this, ConfirmAXI.class);
                    intent.putExtra("mylist", selectedPID);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    displayError("You've selected " + selectedPlayerDetailsList.size() +
                            ", please select " + playerA + " to continue");
//                    displayError();
                }


            }
        });

    }
```

```
 void displayTeamAList() {

        i = -1;
//        String str = "", str1 = "";

        tv_head.setText(preview_head + teamA);
        tv_playerA.setText("Team A players/side  :  " + playerA);

        Log.d("matchid", "select 11, displayTeamAList : " + matchid);

//        progress.dismiss();

        RealmResults<Player> results = realm.where(Player.class).
                equalTo("matchid", matchid).
                equalTo("team", 1).
                sort("playerID", Sort.ASCENDING).
                findAll();

        results.load();
        Log.d("results1", "select 11, displayTeamAList : " + results);

        squad_count = results.size();
        selectedPlayers = new boolean[squad_count];

        teamA_table = findViewById(R.id.teamA_table);

        for (Player player : results) {

            ++count;

            playerDetailsList.add(player);

            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50));
            row.setPadding(10, 25, 10, 25);
//            row.setShowDividers(2);

            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
            cb.setText(player.getPlayerName());// + str + str1);
            cb.setId(i);
            row.addView(cb);

            teamA_table.addView(row);

            ++i;
            selectedPlayers[i] = false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you checking this documentation and understand how Shared Prefs work and how to use them:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

They are mainly used to save a specific state of something so they could be useful in your case.

Good luck!